# Right nav drops below content; some browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem.  I have [this site](http://techavid.com/infogroup) and within my interior(not homepage all other pages) pages there is a right nav.  When the page loads the right nav drops below the content, but when I refresh the page the right nav fixes it itself (Firefox 2 especially).

Anyone ever seen this before and what did you do to fix it?

Comment: The source of your page is `index.php`. Can't help you with that

Answer (score 1):

Looked at your website. On the homepage running Firefox 3.5.7 and your News and Events section was spilling over. I know unrelated to your current problem. Using web developer add-in probably need to adjust your CSS height.

## dhtmlgoodies_scrolldiv {

height:500px;
width:530px;
}

The right nav on the other pages was working for me the oldest browser I have is IE 7. Might want to provide a screen shot along with any CSS used for this section.